# In Win ie6,just use css,is it possible to achieve this layout?

Tags: css

```
    <div class="news">
        <span class="newsTitle"> This is a news title</span> 
        <span class="newIcon"></span> 
    </div>
```

I want to achieve this result:

1.The max-width of <div class="news"> is 300px, if overflow hidden ;
2.The number of the news title's words have no limit;
3.The icon "new" always display.

in win ie6 ,it is possible ?how to write the  css ?

Comment: OK wo will show demo next time

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible but you need to set a width on the newIcon forcing the newsTitle span to adjust appropriately.

here is some code to get you started

```
.news {
 width:300px;  
    background:#DFD; /* just to show layout, remove when ready to use */
    clear:both;
}
.newsTitle {
    float:left;   
    background:#DDF; /* just to show layout, remove when ready to use */
}

.newIcon {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
      display:inline-block;
   background: #FDD; /*just as a sample remove when ready to use it*/
   float:right; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BqwH/1/)

Comment: if the number of newsTitle words are very large,in this demo,newIcon will be display none